# change password user laravel 5.3

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-5

I want to create form with 3 field (old_password, new_password, confirm_password) with laravel 5.

**View**

old password : 
`{!! Form::password('old_password',['class' => 'form-control']) !!}`

New Password : `{!! Form::password('password',['class' => 'form-control']) !!}`

Confirm New Password : `{!! Form::password('verify_password',['class' => 'form-control']) !!}`

**Controller when user register**

```
public function postRegister(Request $request)
{
    $rules = [
        'email'             =>  'required|email|unique:users',
        'confirm_email'     =>  'required|same:email',
        'password'          =>  'required|min:8|regex:/^(?=\S*[a-z])(?=\S*[!@#$&*])(?=\S*[A-Z])(?=\S*[\d])\S*$/',
        'verify_password'   =>  'required|same:password',
    ];

    $messages = [
        'email.required'            => 'email tidak boleh kosong',
        'password.required'         => 'password tidak boleh kosong',
        'password.min'              => 'Password harus minimal 8 karakter',
        'password.regex'            => 'Format password harus terdiri dari kombinasi huruf besar, angka dan karakter spesial (contoh:!@#$%^&*?><).',
        'verify_password.required'  => 'Verify Password tidak boleh kosong',
        'email.email'               => 'Format Email tidak valid',
        'email.unique'              => 'Email yang anda masukkan telah digunakan',
        'verify_password.same'      => 'Password tidak sama!',
    ];

    $this->validate($request,$rules,$messages);


    $newUser = $this->user->create([
        'email'         =>  $request->email,
        'password'      =>  \Hash::make($request->password),
    ]);
    $this->activationService->sendActivationMail($newUser);

    return redirect('/account/login')->with('success', 'Check your email');
}
```

I'm new in laravel, i've read some similar problem to change password in stackoverflow but it didn't help me.

How should I write code in my controller for change password user?.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you can use built-in passwordcontroller.

Comment: If you want to manually, you must research on this `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords\PasswordController.php` page.

Comment: Check this https://www.5balloons.info/setting-up-change-password-with-laravel-authentication/

Answer (score 60, accepted):

This is change password form

```
<form id="form-change-password" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/user/credentials') }}" novalidate class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="col-md-9">             
    <label for="current-password" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Current Password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"> 
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="current-password" name="current-password" placeholder="Password">
      </div>
    </div>
    <label for="password" class="col-sm-4 control-label">New Password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
      </div>
    </div>
    <label for="password_confirmation" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Re-enter Password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password_confirmation" name="password_confirmation" placeholder="Re-enter Password">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-6">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Create rules

```
public function admin_credential_rules(array $data)
{
  $messages = [
    'current-password.required' => 'Please enter current password',
    'password.required' => 'Please enter password',
  ];
  
  $validator = Validator::make($data, [
    'current-password' => 'required',
    'password' => 'required',
    'password_confirmation' => 'required|same:password',     
  ], $messages);

  return $validator;
}
```

User controller method to changes password

use Validator;

```
public function postCredentials(Request $request)
{
  if(Auth::Check())
  {
    $request_data = $request->All();
    $validator = $this->admin_credential_rules($request_data);
    if($validator->fails())
    {
      return response()->json(array('error' => $validator->getMessageBag()->toArray()), 400);
    }
    else
    {  
      $current_password = Auth::User()->password;           
      if(Hash::check($request_data['current-password'], $current_password))
      {           
        $user_id = Auth::User()->id;                       
        $obj_user = User::find($user_id);
        $obj_user->password = Hash::make($request_data['password']);
        $obj_user->save(); 
        return "ok";
      }
      else
      {           
        $error = array('current-password' => 'Please enter correct current password');
        return response()->json(array('error' => $error), 400);   
      }
    }        
  }
  else
  {
    return redirect()->to('/');
  }    
}
```

Comment: Why are you checking if the current password has minimum 8 characters? Maybe the user has a password that's less than 8 characters and he need to change it to >= 8.

Comment: Yes of course, but that's something where the code can fail ;)

Comment: Haha, nice to see that you agreed ;)

Comment: admin_credential_rules & postCredentials use in the same controller right?  show eror when submit like this : ErrorException in AccountController.php line 1221:
Undefined property: App\Http\Controllers\AccountController::$user_service

Comment: admin_credential_rules are define in my user_service... you can also define in this method.

Comment: Remove user_service if you add validation in controller

Comment: I just remove user_service ,but still get eror. like this : FatalErrorException in AccountController.php line 1207:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Validator' not found

Comment: line 1207 is :  $validator = Validator::make($data, [

Comment: Add line ' use Validator; ' you need to use validator

Comment: also need add line 'use Hash;'  and now change password has succesfully update. 

I really appreciate your answer every detail. This greatly helps my job. thank you so much Komal :)

Comment: Welcome!! Please accept the answer if it was helpful.. have a nice day :)

Comment: Hai komal, 1 last question :D , how to make a messages not come into json? because all of my eror message become popup. not as json

Comment: Then return like this  := return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();

Comment: Thank you again :)

Comment: Nicely done Komal. I can't believe this feature does not come out of box with Laravel! After all, logged in users may need to change their passwords just as much as users who forget their password! :)

Comment: @DigiOzMultimedia Thank you :)

Comment: Is it really needed to have `same:password` twice, on both rules for `password` and `password_confirmation`?

Answer (score 12):

I am explain here another method to change user password
***changepassword.blade.php***

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Change password</div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    @if (session('error'))
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            {{ session('error') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif
                        @if (session('success'))
                            <div class="alert alert-success">
                                {{ session('success') }}
                            </div>
                        @endif
                    <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('changePassword') }}">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('current-password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="new-password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Current Password</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="current-password" type="password" class="form-control" name="current-password" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('current-password'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('current-password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('new-password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="new-password" class="col-md-4 control-label">New Password</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="new-password" type="password" class="form-control" name="new-password" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('new-password'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('new-password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="new-password-confirm" class="col-md-4 control-label">Confirm New Password</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="new-password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="new-password_confirmation" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Change Password
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

This is route in **web.php**

```
Route::post('/changePassword','HomeController@changePassword')->name('changePassword');
```

**Controller Method**

```
public function changePassword(Request $request){

        if (!(Hash::check($request->get('current-password'), Auth::user()->password))) {
            // The passwords matches
            return redirect()->back()->with("error","Your current password does not matches with the password you provided. Please try again.");
        }

        if(strcmp($request->get('current-password'), $request->get('new-password')) == 0){
            //Current password and new password are same
            return redirect()->back()->with("error","New Password cannot be same as your current password. Please choose a different password.");
        }

        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'current-password' => 'required',
            'new-password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);

        //Change Password
        $user = Auth::user();
        $user->password = bcrypt($request->get('new-password'));
        $user->save();

        return redirect()->back()->with("success","Password changed successfully !");

    }
```

i have follow that link :- https://www.5balloons.info/setting-up-change-password-with-laravel-authentication/

Comment: Thank you, these are the code snippets that are missing in the tutorial that you referred to. All together gave me a nice solution for Laravel 5.7

Comment: This one works nice for me. Thank you! 

Comment: Thanks bro it worked!! don't forget import this classes in your controller:                       use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash; 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

Answer (score 2):

This is how I do this with Laravel 5.8:

**View**

Confirm password must be something like this:

```
{!! Form::password('password_confirmation', ['class' => 'form-control'']) !!}
```

Because Laravel provides out the box a field [confirmed rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-confirmed).

Create a form request and put this inside the rules part:

```
use App\Rules\IsCurrentPassword;

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'old_password' => ['required', new IsCurrentPassword],
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
    ];
}
```

Let's use artisan to generate a rule that verifies if `old_password` is the real current password:

```
php artisan make:rule IsCurrentPassword
```

And put this inside the passes method of rule generated:

```
/**
 * Determine if the validation rule passes.
 *
 * @param  string  $attribute
 * @param  mixed  $value
 * @return bool
 */
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    $current_password = auth()->user()->password;
    return Hash::check($value, $current_password);
}
```

Do not forget to import `Hash`:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
```

**Controller**

All you need to do in your controller is this:

```
auth()->user()->update([
    'password' => Hash::make($request->password)
]);
```

And tada :) Hope I help.

Answer (score 0):

**changePassword.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <!-- header logo: style can be found in header.less -->
    <header class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                <a href="index.php" class="logo">
                    <!-- Add the class icon to your logo image or logo icon to add the margining -->
                    <img src="img/airbus-logo.png" />
                </a></div>
                <!-- Header Navbar: style can be found in header.less -->
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    @include('partials._userModal')
                    @include('partials._menu')
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Right side column. Contains the navbar and content of the page -->
            <aside class="content files-list clearfix">
                <h2>
                @if(Auth::check())
                Welcome {{ Auth::user()->fullName }}
                @endif
                </h2>
                    <div class="col-xs-5">
                        <h4>Change password</h4><br />
                        @if($errors->any())
                            @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                                <p style='padding:15px;' class='bg-danger'>{{ $error }}</p>
                            @endforeach
                        @endif
                        @if(Request::get('errorMessage') !== null)
                            <p style='padding:15px;' class='bg-danger'>{{ Request::get('errorMessage') }}</p>
                        @endif
                        <form method="post">
                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                           <div class="placeholder">Current Password</div>
                            <input style="max-width:200px;" placeholder='Current password' name="oldpass" id="oldpass"  class="form-control" type="password"><br>
                            <div class="placeholder">New password</div>
                            <input style="max-width:200px;" placeholder='New password' name="password" id="password"  class="form-control" type="password"><br>
                            <div class="placeholder">Confirm password</div>
                            <input id="password_confirmation" style="max-width:200px;" placeholder='Confirm password' name="password_confirmation"  class="form-control" type="password">
                            <hr>
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save">
                        </form>    
                    </div>
            </aside>
            <!-- /.right-side -->
        </div>
        <div style="  height: 155px;"></div>
        <div id="footer">
            <div class="container"> © Airbus Group 2015 </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ./wrapper -->
    <!-- <script src="js/hub/demo.js" type="text/javascript"></script> -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var bHeight = $("body").height();
        var wHeight = $( window ).height();
        if(bHeight < wHeight){
            $("#footer").addClass("absolute");
        }else{
            $("#footer").removeClass("absolute");
        }
        if (!$.support.htmlSerialize && !$.support.opacity){
            $(".placeholder").show();
        }
    });
</script>
@endsection
```

**Controller Post Function**

```
public function postChangePassword(Request $request)
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'oldpass' => 'required|min:6',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6',
            'password_confirmation' => 'required|same:password',
        ],[
            'oldpass.required' => 'Old password is required',
            'oldpass.min' => 'Old password needs to have at least 6 characters',
            'password.required' => 'Password is required',
            'password.min' => 'Password needs to have at least 6 characters',
            'password_confirmation.required' => 'Passwords do not match'
        ]);

        $current_password = \Auth::User()->password;           
        if(\Hash::check($request->input('oldpass'), $current_password))
        {          
          $user_id = \Auth::User()->id;                       
          $obj_user = User::find($user_id);
          $obj_user->password = \Hash::make($request->input('password'));
          $obj_user->save(); 
          return view('auth.passwords.changeConfirmation');
        }
        else
        {           
          $data['errorMessage'] = 'Please enter correct current password';
          return redirect()->route('user.getChangePassword', $data);
        }  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code too for resetting the password.

```
public function passwordReset(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();
    $validated = $request->validate(
        [
            'current_password' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed'
        ]
    );
    //Change Password
    $username = Auth::user();
    $name = $username->username;
    $currentpassword = $input['current_password'];
    $password = $input['password'];
    $result = DB::table('user_security')
        ->where('username', $name)
        ->get();

    $cpassword =  $result[0]->password;
    if (Hash::check($currentpassword, $cpassword)) {
        $insert = DB::table('user_security')
            ->where('username', $name)
            ->update([
                'password' =>  Hash::make($password)
            ]);
        return redirect('viewprofile');
    } else {
        return redirect('changepassword');
    }
}
```