# How to let users change their own passwords in Laravel 7.x?

Tags: laravel, authentication, passwords, laravel-7

There are [numerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39586104/change-password-user-laravel-5-3) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56305196/laravel-5-8-change-password-functionality) about how to allow users to change their passwords, but many of these are for older version of Laravel. What is the correct way for Laravel v7.x in 2020?

Comment: I've just created laravel user change password. the cleanest way to update password. check this out https://gist.github.com/Aslam97/4c320dac0c50f3bbfd64164ad8fdd61a

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Firstly, let's create a form for the user.

A couple of notes on this form:

- I have kept the form as simple as possible to make it readable - the CSRF token gets created automatically by Form::open
- You should *only* use 'password' as field name where password managers should autofill it. Some answers suggest using 'password' as the new password field name, which creates a really bad UX

  ```
  {{Form::open(array('url' => '/account/change-password'))}}
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

  <div class="form-group">

      <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
              <label for="password" class="control-label">Current Password</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
              {{Form::password('password', array('id' => 'password', 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Password'))}}
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
              <label for="new-password" class="control-label">New Password</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
              {{Form::password('new-password', array('id' => 'new-password', 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'New Password'))}}
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
              <label for="new-password-confirmation" class="control-label">Re-enter
                  Password</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
              {{Form::password('new-password-confirmation', array('id' => 'new-password-confirmation', 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Confirm Password'))}}
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Change Password</button>
  </div>
  {{Form::close()}}
  ```

## Now in the controller you want to handle the request, let's change the password.

A couple of notes about this:

- We validate that the password is not a common one - the list used here is not exhaustive (and all lowercase) and I suggest you update it with [the common passwords](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_the_most_common_passwords) that are equal to or above your minimum length
- Speaking of min length, 8 characters should be your starting point in this day and age
- Lastly, don't validate the length of the password confirmation - it'll just give you two errors (since it is already being done)
- Finally, this doesn't audit the password change. Use something like [Laravel Auditing](http://www.laravel-auditing.com/) or even just send an email.

**Account.php**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

 /**
 * Change users password
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
 */
public function changePassword(Request $request)
{
    if(Auth::Check())
    {
        $requestData = $request->All();
        $validator = $this->validatePasswords($requestData);
        if($validator->fails())
        {
            return back()->withErrors($validator->getMessageBag());
        }
        else
        {
            $currentPassword = Auth::User()->password;
            if(Hash::check($requestData['password'], $currentPassword))
            {
                $userId = Auth::User()->id;
                $user = User::find($userId);
                $user->password = Hash::make($requestData['new-password']);;
                $user->save();
                return back()->with('message', 'Your password has been updated successfully.');
            }
            else
            {
                return back()->withErrors(['Sorry, your current password was not recognised. Please try again.']);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Auth check failed - redirect to domain root
        return redirect()->to('/');
    }
}

/**
 * Validate password entry
 *
 * @param array $data
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
 */
public function validatePasswords(array $data)
{
    $messages = [
        'password.required' => 'Please enter your current password',
        'new-password.required' => 'Please enter a new password',
        'new-password-confirmation.not_in' => 'Sorry, common passwords are not allowed. Please try a different new password.'
    ];

    $validator = Validator::make($data, [
        'password' => 'required',
        'new-password' => ['required', 'same:new-password', 'min:8', Rule::notIn($this->bannedPasswords())],
        'new-password-confirmation' => 'required|same:new-password',
    ], $messages);

    return $validator;
}

/**
 * Get an array of all common passwords which we don't allow
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function bannedPasswords(){
    return [
        'password', '12345678', '123456789', 'baseball', 'football', 'jennifer', 'iloveyou', '11111111', '222222222', '33333333', 'qwerty123'
    ];
}
```

Comment: Hello just wanted to ask about this I constantly keep getting _"The POST method is not supported for this route"._  I try all the other routes too but Its not working(im new to laravel)

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-confirmed for password confirmation use dedicated rule.